# Displaying disks without partitions in openSUSE Leap 4.21

Tags: partition, opensuse, virtual-machine, vmware

I am trying to allocate a Linux partition to a disk using an openSUSE VM (in VMPlayer). I have tried running `sfdisk -l` to find the disk, but when I do so I can only see drives with an existing Linux partition, not the USB drive with no allocated partitions. Is there a way of displaying drives that just contain unallocated drive-space and getting openSUSE to partition the drive?

Comment: I am now wondering if because VMWare player is designed to run in a Windows environment it is only able to see Windows partitioned external drives? Does anyone know if this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that I don't know much about openSUSE, but under Debian there is a package called `util-linux`.

There you'll find a tool called "lsblk", which will list all your
installed block-devices, except RAM-Disks.

Just type: `lsblk`

Comment: Hhhhm, doesn't appear to be showing up. Perhaps something to do with the VM. Thanks, though. I'm sure the tools will be useful, and ```lsblk``` shows me the ROM partition, which I couldn't see before.

Comment: I also have no experience with VM-Player, but in VirtualBox you have to configure USB passthrough to have your USB devices present in VMs.

Comment: Thanks. I will give Virtual Box a try see if I have more luck.

Comment: Ok, that was no advertisement for VBox. More intended to check if VMWare also needs some kind of USB passthrough configuration. But yes, give VBox a try ;-)  Years ago I switched from VMWare to VBox and I feel more comfortable with it. Only my opinion :D

Comment: I'll have a check into pass-through config. Appears related to many issues I have faced with tech recently.

Comment: OK, good luck! Let me know about your experience with VBox.

Comment: I gave up in the end and just downloaded the file separately. I'll install VMBox on muh new openSUSE partition and have a play around...